# getting the total count of search results in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, count

How to get the total count of results, in the search results page in wordpress ... i think my question is clear .i need the total number of search results that displayed in  the search results page .And also need to find the count of results from page and post separately
what i have tried is

```
    <?php echo count($posts); ?>
```

by using this i got the total number of search results . but i also need the count of pages and posts in the search results

Comment: Hi Adarsh, welcome to StackOverflow! As it currently stands, your question is very broad, shows no attempt to solve the problem, and also has two tags that aren't very relevant to your question. The first thing you should do is post any code that you have made that tries to solve your problem, and tell us what doesn't work about it so that we can help you find a solution. The next thing you should do is tag your question with more relevant tags, such as the *specific* technologies you're using on your site. (JavaScript, PHP, jQuery, etc.). If you do this, you're more likely to get help!

Comment: Another tip is to use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) if you want to loop on your posts and get its total count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$allsearch = new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=0"); 
echo $allsearch ->found_posts.' results found.';
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more please visit,

[Result Count in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/display-search-term-and-result-count-in-wordpress/)

[Display Search Result Count](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108865/display-search-result-count)

Comment: how to get the count of pages and posts individually

Comment: please check this for the all post counts and for pages pass the 
value in WP_Query 'post_type' => 'page' https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31254/get-post-count-of-current-loop-when-using-multiple-queries-on-one-page

Answer (score 14):

Once you are already in a search query, you can as well use the global $wp_query.

See example below:

```
<?php
   global $wp_query;
   $not_singular = $wp_query->found_posts > 1 ? 'results' : 'result'; // if found posts is greater than one echo results(plural) else echo result (singular)
   echo $wp_query->found_posts . " $not_singular found";
?>
```

Comment: this solution is much better, because you have all ready the global $wp_query, no need to get it again like in the accepted answer

Comment: Also for me this solution is the correct one, it's not necessary to make a new query it just wastes time and resources. Please @Adarsh mark this as accepted!