# get Number of Found Posts on Results Page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to display the total number of found posts on results page in WordPress. For example "If someone searches for 'cat' it should display count for posts with the term 'cat'

My problem with post_count didn't work

thanks

Comment: Just wrap the queried array/object by count php function, which would return the array length

Comment: I would say add more explanation to your question, Is there a pagination on results page? If so do you need count per page or from total found results(includes from all pages) and other such important parameters to your issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349511/getting-the-total-count-of-search-results-in-wordpress

Comment: Can you convert this code into a function and get the output with a shortcode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.